# How would this SQL join work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, "Users" and "Jobs".

Users Table:

```
UserID
Username
Password
AccountType
Forename
Surname
ContactNumber
EmailAddress
```

Jobs Table:

```
JobID
JobTitle
JobDescription
JobLocation
JobDate
JobStartTime
JobPay
PostedDate
PostedBy
AcceptedBy
JobStatus
```

I want to display all of the job rows, and the Username, ContactNumber and EmailAddress from the users table where the "AcceptedBy" in the jobs table is the same as the "UserID" from the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Users ON Jobs.AcceptedBy = Users.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you other example and try to do with your example

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

[here is the tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

enjoy :)